# Facebook.login callback fires multiple times

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook, authentication, callback

I'm using the AS3 SDK and running into a weird issue. I do something like the following:

```
Facebook.init(MY_APP_ID, someHandler);
```

This works ok. At some later point as a result of a user clicking a button in a swf, I do:

```
Facebook.login(someOtherHandler, {perms:"offline_access,publish_stream"});
```

Following the user login/approval in the FB popup window, the "someOtherHandler" method is called, but the problem is it is getting called many times - like upwards of 150. In Firefox this is annoying but still works, and I'm then able to make other calls to the API (lookup their account info, post to their wall, etc.). In IE however, this typically leads to a stack overflow. And honestly, even in Firefox this isn't something I want to live with.

If I do a barebones "hello world" type example to try to reproduce the problem I can't; there the callback only fires the expected single time. I'm trying to isolate what could be causing the callback to be called again and again but the system I'm integrating this into is quite large and so it's taking a very long time. That's also why I'm not posting the real code which I know will make it harder for anyone else to help out, but I'm hoping someone's been down this general road before. Thx.

(EDIT - I have verified that Facebook.login is in fact only being called a single time)

Comment: You didn't say what IDE you are using, but this does sound like some call is if getting called on each frame.

Comment: Not using an IDE for this segment of code, just commandline compilation with mxmlc. My callback method is private and only reference to it is in the Facebook.login call which is immediately preceded by a debug trace that only appears once in my logs. I agree it sounds like it's getting called multiple times but I don't see how that could be.

Comment: Well, if you got it working bare-bones fine just not in your real app then the issue lies in your app. Without more code then the 2 lines you posted I can't be much more help.